# Why I can not use u8 as an index value of a Rust array?

Tags: rust

I am new to Rust, and I am trying to write simple bitwise replacer.

I have this code:

```
const TABLE: [u64; 8] = [
    0xC462A5B9E8D703F1,
    0x68239A5C1E47BD0F,
    0xB3582FADE174C960,
    0xC821D4F670A53E9B,
    0x7F5A816D093EB42C,
    0x5DF692CAB78143E0,
    0x8E25691CF4B0DA37,
    0x17ED05834FA69CB2,
];

fn get_part(u: u64, i: u8) -> u8 {
    ((u & (0xFu64 << (16 - i))) >> (16 - i)) as u8
}

fn process(o: u8, i1: u8, i2: u8) -> u8 {
    let left: u8 = o >> 4;
    let right: u8 = o & 0xF;
    (get_part(TABLE[left], left) << 4) + get_part(TABLE[right], right)
}
```

I got errors like this one:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: std::slice::SliceIndex<[u64]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:15
   |
19 |     (get_part(TABLE[left], left) << 4) + get_part(TABLE[right], right)
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[u64]>` is not implemented for `u8`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<u8>` for `[u64]`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `u8: std::slice::SliceIndex<[u64]>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:19:51
   |
19 |     (get_part(TABLE[left], left) << 4) + get_part(TABLE[right], right)
   |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[u64]>` is not implemented for `u8`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<u8>` for `[u64]`
```

I don't understand why it's illegal to use `u8` as the index value. How can I convert `u8` to a compatible type? I don't even know which type is compatible.

Comment: Please shrink your example by removing irrelevant parts in order to create a [MCVE]. It also appears you are asking two questions. Please only ask one question per StackOverflow post. You can edit your question to improve it. Thanks :)

Comment: It is minimal already, there is only needed code, the error message is from fn process, third statement.

Comment: [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=920371cfd1796115560c01bbd8536f0a&version=stable) is *more minimal*, right? ;-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can look at the documentation for `SliceIndex` by [searching the Rust standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/?search=sliceindex). The list of implementations of this trait at the bottom of the [documentation page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceIndex.html#implementors) indicates that this trait is implemented for `usize` and various `usize` ranges.

This should answer both of your questions: indexing is not implemented for `u8` type and you need to cast `u8` to `usize`.

```
(get_part(TABLE[left as usize], left) << 4) + get_part(TABLE[right as usize], right)
```